# Subscriptions -- Credit Card Required? & OpenGateway Migration

Tags: devdemon, subscriptions, devdemon-subscriptions

1. Can a customer checkout without credit card information by using a voucher? We are using Stripe as the gateway, but certain customers are invoiced differently, (not through Stripe) thinking the vouchers would suffice?
2. How do you add an existing member in ExpressionEngine to a subscription from the EE Control Panel?
3. Have you seen any existing Membrr/Opengateway to Subscriber migrations? Any idea what this process entails while retaining existing subscriptions in OpenGateway using Stripe as the payment gateway?

Answer (score 0):

1. No credit card is needed if someone redeems a voucher. Note: Their subscription is also set to "not" auto-renew.
2. That is currently not possible but will be added very soon. (June/July)
3. We have had several people ask but we never fully automated it, everybody used a mix of re-subscribe or silently subscribe them when they update their payment details. We do want to create an automated version if you want to go forward with it. Get in touch.

Comment: I used the example templates to test #1. Does Stripe JS require a credit card? What about coupons? How do I get around the message from Stripe? "CARD_CREATE: The number parameter is required". I also received. "Could not find payment information". We want to be able to create subscriptions using coupons, but require no credit card info.

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend Charge as a replacement for Membrr/Opengateway... works great!